# Entity locking issue in JAX-RS + JPA

Tags: hibernate, jpa, jax-rs, wildfly, resteasy

I've deployed a REST JSON API, written in Java using JAX-RS (RESTeasy) and JPA (Hibernate) on WildFly 10.

Sometimes, a GET right after a POST take minutes to complete and I get several warnings/errors in the log.

Here's some code:

```
@Stateless
@Path("/articles")
public class ArticleResource {

    @PersistenceContext
    private EntityManager em;

    @POST
    @Consumes("application/json")
    public Response post(Article article) {
        this.em.persist(article);
        URI location = UriBuilder.fromUri("/articles/{id}").build(article.getId());
        return Response.created(location).build();
    }

    @GET
    @Path("/{id}")
    @Produces("application/json")
    public Article get(@PathParam("id") Long id) {
       return this.em.find(Article.class, id);
    }

}
```

Then, if I do this:

```
$ curl -i -X POST --data @article.json http://localhost/articles
```

I get this output immediately:

```
HTTP/1.1 201 Created
...
Location: http://localhost/articles/123
```

and if I immediately issue `curl http://localhost/articles/123`, *sometimes* it takes 4–6 minutes to return the JSON, and in the logs I see this:

```
ERROR [org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper] (EJB default - 4)
IJ031012: Unable to obtain lock in 60 seconds: org.jboss.jca.adapters.jdbc.local.LocalManagedConnection
```

First: why it's trying to get a lock for just a `SELECT`? I guess the lock is requested *before* calling the `EntityManager.find` method, so how can I annotate the `ArticleResource.get` method to instruct the container not to request a lock?

Second: why the lock (which I suppose is being set by the previous `POST` request) isn't released when the `POST` response is committed?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, I don't know, but I would not have expected to see the `@Stateless` session bean being used directly by the rest service. From all of the wildfly examples I have seen I would have expected to see the `@Stateless` session bean injected into the REST service. See:

[MemberResourceRESTService.java](https://github.com/wildfly/quickstart/blob/10.x/kitchensink/src/main/java/org/jboss/as/quickstarts/kitchensink/rest/MemberResourceRESTService.java)

Also, bear in mind that the examples I'm used to seeing are Java EE/JPA examples, like the one referenced, not Hibernate examples. However, I understand they're working on deprecating the Hibernate API and moving to the JPA api.

[Is legacy Criteria API still recommended?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36943426/is-legacy-criteria-api-still-recommended/36943832#36943832)

Comment: Thank you, I refactored my API making `@Stateless` DAOs and injecting them to the REST services.